# Continues animation from certain point onwards?

Tags: animation

I would like to animate an object to rotate contentiously, from a certain time onwards.

Let's say I have a windmill. At the start of the animation it does not rotate. then starts rotating, and continues rotating until the end of the animation.

How can I do this, without manually calculating how many rotations it needs until the end of the animation (which I would need to recalculate whenever I extend the total animation time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 3 keyframes, example:

- At frame 1: windmill's starting point
- At frame 30: the windmill has rotated 20°
- At frame 60: the windmill has rotated 180°

Then in the *Timeline* press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation*, and the movement will go on indefinitely (at the same speed as frame 60). To cancel, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Constant Extrapolation*.

Answer (score 3):

In the Non linear animation window, create a strip for your action and open the options panel (using "N" or clicking on the small arrow at the top right corner of that window) when selecting the action you want to repeat, go to the "Strip" tab and open "action clip" options then, inside repeat select the amount of times you want to repeat this action, if you don't want to calculate the number just change the value until the Strip covers the lenght you're lookig for.

There are many ways you can do this, but this might be the easiest one and "non destructive" for your animation since you can still edit this action later.